# I want to run bash directly interactively but not getting ANSI codes

Tags: java, bash, ansi-escape

I'm creating my own Java-based term program and it works great with SSH and Telnet connections.
But now I want to open a local direct connection like xterm or gnome-terminal do.
I run "bash -i -l" with ProcessBuilder and use getInputStream() / getOutputStream() and it seems to work. (I need to call redirectErrorStream(true))
My only problem is that bash seems to be ignoring the TERM environment variable and is not generating any ANSI codes.  I get a prompt but running 'ls -la' is missing CR's and color.  Plus it's not echoing back the input (like it does over the SSH connection).

I use JCraft's JSch library and call setPtyType("vt100") for the SSH connections.
How would I do that when running bash directly?

I'm not using a pty, is that needed?  Allocating a pty would require native code I think.
If so, how do pty's work.

I've tried to look at xterm source code but that's a mess.  Now I remember why I'll never go back to C code.

Is there a simple solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as `ls` goes, it may be that your `ls` is alias for `ls --color=auto` (you can check this by running `alias ls` in a terminal). In that case, ls will make an educated guess whether to output the color codes. From `man ls`:

> Using color to distinguish file types is  disabled  both  by  default 
>   and  with  --color=never.   With --color=auto, ls emits color codes
>   only when standard output is connected to a terminal.

Many other programs will probably do this kind of thing.

As far as your general studies of terminal emulation goes, "Terminator" seems to do some pty emulation (using a JNI library though) that maybe you can get some ideas from:

http://software.jessies.org/terminator/